# Changing content provider package after refactor

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I forked the IOSchedule app from last year's Google IO. I want to make sure I can get an API key which means I need to sign the application and it doesn't have conflicts with the content provider which means I need to refactor. However every time I try to use the Android Tools > Refactor Package Name, I get issues, namely with modifying a content provider.

This is the tag for the content provider:

```
<provider
android:name="com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider"
android:authorities="com.google.android.apps.iosched"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:syncable="true"
android:writePermission="com.google.android.apps.iosched.permission.WRITE_SCHEDULE" />
```

I've been trying to change it to the following:

```
<provider
android:name="com.google.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider"
android:authorities="org.mrkaiser.android.apps.iosched"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:syncable="true"
android:writePermission="com.google.android.apps.iosched.permission.WRITE_SCHEDULE" />
```

However at runtime I get the following error:

`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329): java.lang.NullPointerException`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.MyScheduleFragment.onLoadFinished(MyScheduleFragment.java:175)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.MyScheduleFragment.onLoadFinished(MyScheduleFragment.java:1)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:424)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:392)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:103)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:81)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:35)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:221)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)`
`04-22 21:29:13.818: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I try and refactor the packages R gets out of sync along with some xml files and I can't recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually figured it out. The ScheduleContract in the project claims a content authority. If that isn't pointed to the correct package it'll fail to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rename your provider also....and also if you are using eclipse try to rename your package through it. Try renaming it like this:

```
android:name="org.mrkaiser.android.apps.iosched.provider.ScheduleProvider"
android:authorities="org.mrkaiser.android.apps.iosched"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:syncable="true"
android:writePermission="org.mrkaiser.android.apps.iosched.permission.WRITE_SCHEDULE"
```

and also rename your package name through eclipse. It will update all the references. Also change the package name in androidmanifest.xml